# Can Hive and Hbase support 4 hundreds million data? or which is better?

Tags: postgresql, hive, hbase

We would like to store and analyze 4 hundreds million records data by hive(PostgreSQL) and hbase, can Hive and Hbase support 4 hundreds million data? If can't, is there any better choice?

Comment: Well, you can try and tell us the results. You can take into account Elastic Search.

Comment: Hi, thanks I will try both hive and hbase, and thank you so much for telling me Elastic Search